New flutter project cannot run (java version error)
When I create a new flutter app, I got an error :
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/username/flutter-projects/validator_app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties.

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Then I installed the related Java version with Brew.

brew install openjdk@17

Also updated path variable in .zshrc bash file.

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/

Then I confirmed the current version with the following:

java -version

Flutter project still not starting and gives the same error.

Finally, I updated my android/gradle.properties file with this line :

org.gradle.java.home=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17

This worked.
